# Is there a way to make the BLAZOR app in vs2019 "easy" for a CRUD (views) web application?

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2019, blazor-server-side

I am looking at tutorials on YouTube and it seems there is A LOT of work to get what we old-timers call a web-forms functionality conversion into MVC or BLAZOR (which I think utilizes the MVC pattern).  I know there are no built-in fancy controls in BLAZOR.
We are trying to port our existing Web-Forms project to C# and BLAZOR.
SQL-Server DB, many queries, previously used DAL and BLL effectively and "easy" to code and modify.
How are templates like BOOTSTRAP or similar used?
Will the templates or fancy CSS help with the look of the views?
Do I have to may my own smart "component/controls" with @code { }?
Seeking best practice here.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered any third party tools?  I've used Telerik Grid for Blazor and it's designed for CRUD operations.  It makes the job easy if you can make the investment.  https://www.telerik.com/blazor-ui

Comment: Not really considering based on the cost.  We have learned from some tutorials, but considering a complex application to use as "data-entry", and (online) "reporting".  Most of the tutorials demo single table CRUD examples.  We have db-VIEWS to collect record from different db-tables..  I am not sure if that is feasible in BLAZOR. Input-validation is paramount to this application -- implying warnings of incorrect inputs, choices like: "Accept this value or re-enter?"  I thank you for your comment and is very valid.  Wish we could afford it.  Thx.

Comment: I think Blazor will be good news for you, because the things you're asking about are features that are central to the framework.  You can do whatever SQL work you want in Blazor.  .NET 5 includes a standard SQL library, and you can add Dapper to shorten things down a lot.  Almost all the tutorial series I've seen show how to do CRUD database operations, including Blazor's pretty robust built-in validation.  I do a LOT of database work on my company's site, and don't feel limited in any way at all.

Answer (score 0):

Especially when using the server-side Blazor hosting model, this doesn't necessarily have to be all that challenging. Blazor provides a different take on web development than is available with MVC. At it's core (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in more detail), you're splitting out all the piecemeal functionality of a page into reusable components that you reference in still other components or pages (which are components that are routable).

The idea is that you can move closer to traditional web development using HTML and CSS to build the layout of each component and if you must use JavaScript, you can trivially invoke it using the [interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0) functionality.

As such, sure, you can use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com), [Bulma](https://bulma.io), [Foundation](https://get.foundation) and other CSS frameworks as starting points for your styling needs. To use them, you can download to your project and build them as part of a [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) or [grunt](https://gruntjs.com) pipeline, or just reference the CDN in your _Host.cshtml file in the head as you would any other webpage and use the documented classes to decorate your HTML elements.

You specify the HTML that builds out each component up top (including placing other components inline) and can use the [Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c) to use C# expressions and variables inline (imagine the top is like a partial class with the code below in your `@code` block). Generally, you can rely on [event bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to handle reactions to events in your component (identifying the event type in the markup and pointing to the method that handles it below in your `@code` block).

If you need more granular and custom styling, Blazor supports [CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0), allowing you to specify CSS that's used only in instances of that component and not polluting the global namespace. There are also third-party packages like [BlazorStyled](https://github.com/chanan/BlazorStyled) that enable you to inline your CSS classes within your `@code` block if that's more your cup of tea.

And finally to your existing code. One of the greatest joys of server-side is that all the code is still running on the server - it's only the rendered output of this code that's sent to the client, so most, if not all of your existing backend code should Just Work. The bulk of your work them will just be wiring up the output to new HTML markup to display everything. For your forms, Blazor offers [built-in validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0) based off traditional `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation` attributes. If you're able to utilize EF Core as an ORM for your SQL instance, they've got [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0) dedicated to this sort of integration.

I've generally found Blazor (server-side) quite a breeze to use and an exemplary tool for allowing me to re-use my existing .NET investments without any real changes.

If you've got any other specific asks, ping me with a comment and I'd be happy to edit my answer to address them.

Comment: ...thank you for a comprehensive answer and reply.  I have many years of DB and UI programming and am reasonably proficient in Web-Forms, but they are sealing up that tomb in the near future.  Making the shift now, seems rather different since I am used to handling "page/form state" in the SESSION object between client and server.  Our "forms/pages" need to respond to user-roles AND be able to pass context data between a "form" and a child "sub-form" and the "page-header".  I am looking at that now.  Thank you!!!!!

Comment: While the server- and WASM-based models of Blazor differ, the former manages everything in a single circuit on a per-client basis so you might some familiarity in that. Because it all runs on the server, you don't have to manage state between the two (everything on the client is only what's rendered and sent over there). Because the services are singletons, you can use them to maintain state or communicate via components with parameters/event callbacks (aligned with your form, child form and header).